# Firestore: filter for user generated content

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

My data structure looks like:

```
collection
-- id_1 (document)
---- rating : 0
---- date : 1506266576364
---- tags : { car : true, boat : true }
-- id_2 (document)
---- rating : 1
---- date : 1506266540000
---- tags : { car : true, plane : true }
```

And my query looks like:

```
ref
.where('tags.car', '==', true)
.orderBy('rating', 'desc')
.limit(5)
```

In words: I want to retrieve all documents that have the given tag assigned, ordered by rating, limited to 5. So this is the top 5 rated using this tag.

Firestore tells me that this is no problem if I create a composite index for this query and tells me how to create it.
This is not possible for me because the tags are user generated, and as far as I understood, I cannot create composite indices programmatically.

I am not sure if it makes a difference when using a subcollection instead of an object.

What is a possible way to query for user generated content?

Answer (score -1):

As I read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#compound_queries) you only need a custom index when you combine an equality operator `==` with a range operator e.g. `>`.

> You can also chain multiple where() methods to create more specific queries (logical AND). However, to combine the equality operator (==) with a range comparison (<, <=, >, or >=), make sure to create a custom index.

Therefore your query should be valid as is. No need to create any custom indices.

If you want to dynamically query a tag, then you can (assuming you are using ES6) do the following:

```
ref.
  .where(`tags.${tag}`, '==', true)
  .orderBy('rating', 'desc')
  .limit(5)
```

Comment: I also read the documentation and came to the same conclusion as you did. However, when executing the exact query you posted, I get the following: `FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here: [link](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/.....)`

Comment: You can copy and paste the link that it gives you and create the index, it doesn't hurt having it :) @keno

Comment: Yes, I know. But this wont help me very much, as there will be a lot of tags created by other users. I cannot create every index manually to every tag, because tags are user created. The suggested index includes the tag. e.g: index on 'tags.car'.

Comment: Maybe try adding an index on just 'tags', no '.tag'